# Using C to replace the first half of a file with the second and truncating?

Tags: c, file

So I have a big file, and once it reaches a certain size, I want to totally remove the first half and shift the second half down, effectively making it half the size. Heres's what I'm thinking:

```
FILE *fp, *start;
int ch, block_length, filesize;
char c;

//open the file and initialize pointers
fp = fopen(FILEPATH, "rb+");
start = fp;
rewind(start);

//Check the size of the file
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
filesize = ftell(fp);    

if(filesize >= LOG_MAX_FILE_SIZE)
{
  //Go to middle of file
  fseek(fp, (-1) * LOG_MAX_FILE_SIZE/2, SEEK_END);

  //Go forwards until you get a new line character to avoid cutting a line in half
  for(;;)
  {
     //Read char
     fread(&ch, 1, 1, fp);

     //Advance pointer
     fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_CUR);

     if( (char)ch == '\n' || ch == EOF)
        break;
  }

  //fp is now after newline char roughly in middle of file

  //Loop over bytes and put them at start of file until EOF
  for(;;)
  {
     //Read char
     fread(&ch, 1, 1, fp);

     //Advance pointer
     fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_CUR);

     if(ch != EOF)
     {
        c = (char)ch;
        fwrite(&c,1,1,start);
        fflush(start);

        //Advance start
        fseek(start, 1, SEEK_CUR);
     }

     else
        break;
  }

  //Calculate length of this new file
  block_length = ftell(start);

  //Go back to start
  rewind(start);

  //Truncate file to block length
  ftruncate(fileno(start), block_length);

}
```

But, this seems to be doing some very very strange things (padding the file with 'f''s, mixing up lines and some characters inside them, etc.).  Does anyone have any ideas as to what I may be doing wrong in this code?  Thanks beforehand!

Comment: it's opened in "rb+" mode, as it says in the code comment.

Comment: I don't want to see what the comment says: show the code! The comment could say I've won the lottery, but I haven't....

Comment: Good point. Code is there now.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem I think is that you are using `fseek` while reading.  The call to fread and fwrite advance the file pointer.  If you call fseek, it will then skip the next character.

In the following sequence of code, the `fread` call will read a character and advance the current offset to the next character.  The subsequent `fseek` then skips that character and moves to the next.  So it will read every second character.

```
fread(&ch, 1, 1, fp);
fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_CUR);
```

The same issue exists with the write call (it does not need a subsequent seek).  Also, since the edit to the OP shows that start and fp are the same value, the logic will not be correct (you would need separate file pointers to use that logic).

Answer (score 0):

Having found your start position, you can copy the file in big chunks (say 64 KB at a time), reading from the tail and then skipping towards the start and writing, before skipping back to the tail...

The `ftruncate()` is the final step to release the space.

Consider whether it would be easier to have a read file stream and a write file stream pointing to the same file.  Less seeking on a single stream (so simpler code).  It's what I'd probably do.